# java profiler with flame graph output

Tags: java, profiling

In perl there is a very nice profiler available called NYTProf.

In it's report it includes a [flame graph](http://blog.timbunce.org/2013/04/08/nytprof-v5-flaming-precision/), which makes it very easy to find the bottleneck of the program

Is there an equivalent java profiler which produces the same report?

Comment: Flame graphs are pretty, but not that effective for finding bottlenecks. [*Check the end of this answer.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771)

Comment: I used in perl this module which creates flame graphs and it was very useful for me http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-5.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm

Comment: That's because it helped you find one or a few speedups, right? That's great. Now, do you suppose there are no more to be found? They can hide from flame graphs, and if they are in there, you can go still faster if you find them, and not by just a little. Check out [*false negatives*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262).

Answer (score 1):

Try this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/javaflamegraph

npm install javaflamegraph

npm start