# Getting XHProf visualization (issues with Graphviz and dot) working

Tags: php, profiling, graphviz, dot, xhprof

I installed [XHProf](http://php.net/manual/de/book.xhprof.php) and would like to see call graph visualization. I clicked on `View Full Callgraph` and got following message first:

> failed to execute cmd: " dot -Tpng". stderr: `sh: dot: command not found '

After some googling, I find out, that it's caused by not installed [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). Then I installed it:

```
$ yum install graphviz
```

and tried again. Now I'm getting following error messages:

> failed to execute cmd: " dot -Tpng". stderr: `Error: /usr/lib64/graphviz/config6 is zero sized, or other read error.
>
> Error: /usr/lib64/graphviz/config6 is zero sized, or other read error.
>
> There is no layout engine support for "dot"
>
> Perhaps "dot -c" needs to be run (with installer's privileges) to register the plugins?
>
> '

Indeed executing of `dot -c` causes an error:

```
$ dot -c
Error: /usr/lib64/graphviz/config6 is zero sized, or other read error.
Warning: Could not load "/usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6" - file not found
Warning: Could not load "/usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_xlib.so.6" - file not found
Segmentation fault
```

But the files `libgvplugin_pango.so.6` and `libgvplugin_xlib.so.6` are there and located in `/usr/lib64/graphviz/`:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/graphviz
total 724
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     26 May 19 13:58 libgvplugin_pango.so.6 -> libgvplugin_pango.so.6.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  22408 Sep 19  2012 libgvplugin_pango.so.6.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25 May 19 13:58 libgvplugin_xlib.so.6 -> libgvplugin_xlib.so.6.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  15656 Sep 19  2012 libgvplugin_xlib.so.6.0.0
```

Well, as symlinks. But it should not matter. Anyway, I also tested this case:

```
mv /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6 /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6_DEACT
mv /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_xlib.so.6 /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_xlib.so.6_DEACT
cp /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6.0.0 /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_pango.so.6
cp /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_xlib.so.6.0.0 /usr/lib64/graphviz/libgvplugin_xlib.so.6
```

No effect, still the same errors.

**What is goning wrong here and how to get this working?**

*Environment: VirtualBox VM with CentOS 6 as guest system.*

Comment: Here are [*some reasons*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771) why not to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally got it working.

---

**Short answer**:

I guess the **`yum update`** or/and perhaps the **`ann-libs` installation** might have been the decisive step(-s). But it's just an assumption, therefore I described all the steps, that might be important (s. below).

---

**Detailed answer**:

First I tried to install `graphviz` with related packages:

```
$ yum install 'graphviz*'
```

But the installation didn't work:

```
Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
cairo-1.8.8-3.1.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libpixman-1.so.0()(64bit)
```

Then I tried the same, but added the `graphviz-rhel.repo` to the repositories before:

```
$ cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
$ wget http://www.graphviz.org/graphviz-rhel.repo
$ yum list available 'graphviz*'
$ yum install 'graphviz*'
```

It failed with another error:

```
Error: Package: graphviz-2.38.0-1.el6.x86_64 (graphviz-stable)
           Requires: libANN.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
cairo-1.8.8-3.1.el6.x86_64 has missing requires of libpixman-1.so.0()(64bit)
```

As expected `--skip-broken` didn't lead to success as well.

After that I did multiple things: `yum clean all`, `yum erase 'graphviz*'`, `ann-libs` installation, and `yum update`:

```
$ yum clean all
$ yum install 'graphviz*'
$ yum erase 'graphviz*'
$ cd ~/temp/
$ wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/ann-libs-1.1.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
$ rpm -i ann-libs-1.1.1-4.el6.x86_64.rpm 
$ yum update
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem on some RHEL 6 systems and turns out the problem is with hidden dependencies of Graphviz plugins on some X11 libraries, which I was able to get installed by installing the following rpms:

- `libXau`
- `libxcb`
- `libXext`

So, this solved my problem: `yum install gtk2 libXau libxcb libXext`