# Difference in method ordering on Hot Spots view and Method Statistics view in JProfiler

Tags: java, performance, profiling, jprofiler

I am doing profiling for java application using JProfiler. I wanted to determine the culprit method which consumes most of the run time. For figuring it out, I am looking at two methods (let's assume method name is x and y) in the Hot Spots and Method Statistics sub tabs under CPU views.Listing of these methods which is sorted on the basis of Avg Time are opposite on both of these tabs. Is there any specific reason for it?

Comment: If you expect to be able to find the problem by looking for a "culprit method", it's likely to escape you. There's a [*better way*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771).

Answer (score 1):

The hot spot view shows self-times (without outgoing calls) whereas the method statistics view shows total times, so the times will usually be very different.