# Using GPerf Tool: not working, issue with redirection?

Tags: profiler, gperftools

I'm trying to profile my software in order to optimize it.

I used `gprof` with the compilation flag `-g -pg -O3` but the result are not giving me enough precision.

Here is my Stacktrace of compilation:

```
$: make clean; make;

rm -f ./obj/*.o
rm -f ./bin/mdk-verifier
rm -f ./grammar/modal.output
rm -f ./grammar/modal.tab.h
rm -f ./grammar/*.cpp
rm -f ./lex.backup

bison -d -t -l -v -o ./grammar/modal.tab.c ./grammar/modal.y && mv ./grammar/modal.tab.c ./grammar/modal.tab.cpp
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./grammar/modal.tab.cpp -o ./obj/modal.tab.o
flex -l -b -o./grammar/lex.yy.cpp ./grammar/modal.lex   
g++ -O3 -g -pg -I./include -c ./grammar/lex.yy.cpp -o ./obj/lex.yy.o
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/Kripke.cc -o ./obj/Kripke.o   
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/Term.cc -o ./obj/Term.o 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/BooleanConstant.cc -o ./obj/BooleanConstant.o 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/Variable.cc -o ./obj/Variable.o 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/PropositionalVariable.cc -o ./obj/PropositionalVariable.o 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/Operation.cc -o ./obj/Operation.o 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/BooleanOperation.cc -o ./obj/BooleanOperation.o 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/ModalOperation.cc -o ./obj/ModalOperation.o   
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -I./include -c ./src/Formula.cc -o ./obj/Formula.o 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -fPIC -std=c++11  -o ./obj/Main.o -c ./src/Main.cc 
g++ -O3 -g -pg -static -lprofiler -o ./bin/mdk-verifier ./obj/modal.tab.o ./obj/lex.yy.o ./obj/Kripke.o ./obj/Term.o ./obj/BooleanConstant.o ./obj/PropositionalVariable.o ./obj/Variable.o ./obj/Operation.o ./obj/BooleanOperation.o ./obj/ModalOperation.o ./obj/Formula.o ./obj/Main.o
```

And here is how I call my program:

```
$: ./bin/mdk-verifier ./problem.txt < solution.txt
```

So after execution, everything is fine, I get a `gmon.out` file. I'm executing the command `gprof ./bin/mdk-verifier | more` and I get the following results:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 34.00      2.13     2.13       18   118.33   118.33  ModalOperation::checkBranch(Kripke&, unsigned int)
  ...
  ...
  5.91      4.98     0.37 54684911     0.00     0.00  BooleanOperation::checkBranch(Kripke&, unsigned int)
  4.63      5.27     0.29 54684911     0.00     0.00  PropositionalVariable::checkBranch(Kripke&, unsigned int)
```

And obviously, the count of calls for ModalOperation::checkBranch overflowed... and by making a display everytime I'm entering this function, I indeed made more than 18 calls...

So I thought about using another profiler, more precise and I found [GPerfTools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) by Google.

I wanted to use it, I installed on my Ubuntu:

- libgoogle-perftools-dev
- google-perftools

and by following the [tutorial](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools), They asked me to set the environment variable `CPUPROFILE`

I did and I get:

```
 $: env | grep "CPU"
 CPUPROFILE=./prof.out
```

I also put `-lprofiler` during the linking of my executable, So I thought that everything was okay and that I could start profiling the data in the file `./prof.out`

But unfortunately, this file is not appearing... Nothing is created, so I can't profile anything...

Does anyone has an idea about why the `./prof.out` file is not created and why the profiling is not gathering data ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Best Regards;

Comment: Double-check everything on your end. Your description of what you did looks reasonable.

Comment: Ah. One possible reason could be that your application is still built with -pg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your purpose is to save time in your software. Multiple issues, first the negatives:

- -O3: The compiler can optimize certain things. It cannot optimize the things that only you can optimize. What it *can* do is make them hard to find, by scrambling the code. The time to use -O3 is *after* you've found and fixed what *you* can.
- `gprof` is venerable, but little more. It samples the program counter and counts function calls. [*Here is a list of problems with that.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771)
  It does give you a call graph, but [*speedups can easily hide in that*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771).
- `gperftools` is better (REVISED in response to Aliaksei's comment) because it is a true stack-sampler. Normally it is a "CPU-profiler", in which mode it is blind to any time spent in blocking, like I/O or sleep. However, if you set environment variable [*`CPUPROFILE_REALTIME=1`*](https://gperftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html) you can make it sample on wall-clock time, so it will see I/O, sleeps, and other blocking system calls.
  It has numerous output options.
  It does not seem to make it easy to see a small random selection of the actual stack samples themselves, with line number information.

Now for the positive:

- There is a method (not a product) that many people use, [*random pausing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).
  The idea is to substitute quality for quantity - get stack samples *at the right time*.
  Very few are needed, like 5, 10, or 20, during the time interval of interest. If something takes 95% of time, every stack sample has a 95% chance of being at the right time.
  Then *examine each stack sample* to see what's happening - don't just summarize / accumulate / average / do pretend statistics.
  (If this is done manually under a debugger, you can also examine data variables, giving even more understanding of why the program is spending that moment in time.)
  The object is to *find* the problem, not *measure* it.
  Anything you can see that could be avoided, if you see it on more than one sample, will save substantial time.
  [*Here's how much.*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)
  The fewer samples you need to see it twice, the more it will save.
  If you want to see exactly what it saves you, just use a stopwatch before and after.
  And don't do it just once. Every time you fix a problem, you uncover more, so if you keep on doing it, you may be able to get [*dramatic speedups*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/302345/2429).

Comment: btw gperftools' cpu profiler can also do wall clock time profiling.