# GPROF flat profile empty result

Tags: gcc, flat-file, gprof

I'm trying to use gprof (I have to use gprof - no other option is available) when I get the flat file the result is empty even though everything works fine.

By the way, the code is in c so I'm using gcc.

Result:

```
Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
no time accumulated

%   cumulative   self              self     total           
time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name
```

What can I do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Please share you sources and compilation/profiling command lines.

Comment: Even if it worked, it wouldn't tell you much. [*Look here.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36062120/23771)

Answer (score 4):

You can use gcc -no-pie option as a workaround.

Comment: I had to specify `-fno-pie` instead. gcc 4.4.5 on i386 here.