# How to exclude namespace from gprof?

Tags: c++, gprof

I am using gprof to profile my application. I use gprof2dot to produce graphs, but the graphs tend to be large because there is plenty of "chain" calls of boost:: functions. Is there a way to remove this not necessary boost:: functions from the gprof output?

I can use --no-time=symspec option, but this allows only to exclude one function, not the whole namespace.

Comment: It's hard to get around that problem with any profiler that produces call graphs. What you need is something that tells you only about things that actually take time. Check out [*this post*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25870103/23771).